# Correct syntax for the htmx hx-request attribute (credentials, noHeaders)

Tags: django-templates, htmx

I have a Django project where I'm making some fairly extensive use of HTMX to insert hints, errors, etc. within the forms to assist the user in filling them out correctly.  Here's an example of the way I'm structuring it in my templates:

```
    <div id="user_entry_1a_slot"
    hx-get="{% url 'user_entry_1b' %}"
    hx-trigger="keyup"
    hx-target="#user_entry_1b_slot"
    hx-include="this">
        <p>Enter a three character alphanumeric identifier:
            <input type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" name="ti_threecharid"></input>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="user_entry_1b_slot">
    </div>
```

The `user_entry_1b` view then looks at what's typed so far and supplies feedback to the user ("Must be three characters", etc.).

Since this is (for me) a learning project as much as a useful application, I'm trying to incorporate the `hx-request` attribute into the request.  What interests me especially are the `credentials` and `noHeaders` options.  I checked [the HTMX documentation](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-request/) but (for me) it isn't especially helpful.  Nor can I find, after googling around, any examples showing how to set these options in the `hx-request`.

Based on what little information is given in the writeup, I tried specifying these options as:

```
    <div id="user_entry_1a_slot"
    hx-get="{% url 'user_entry_1b' %}"
    hx-trigger="keyup"
    hx-request='\"credentials\":"true"'
    hx-target="#user_entry_1b_slot"
    hx-include="this">
```

and

```
    <div id="user_entry_1a_slot"
    hx-get="{% url 'user_entry_1b' %}"
    hx-trigger="keyup"
    hx-request='\"noHeaders\":"true"'
    hx-target="#user_entry_1b_slot"
    hx-include="this">
```

...but neither setting has any effect on the resulting request sent to the `user_entry_1b` view.  I printed out the `request.headers` dictionary before adding these attribute settings and with each attempt above, but the resulting header content was completely identical.  No credentials showed up in the first, and every header was still present in the second.

So -- can anyone assist with the correct syntax for `hx-request`?